# how to connect to a sql server database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hai guys,
        how to connect to a sql server database in asp.net mvc ... I know it can be done easily in asp.net web application using web.config and in the aspx page`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: Why do you think that won't work in an MVC app? Have you tried it?

Comment: no i am just a beginner can you guide me with a method that does it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to a database in MVC the same way you would in an asp.net web app.  There's no difference, save that in a web app you have a code behind, and in MVC you have a controller and presumably a model.  Other than that, creating a connection to your database is completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an ORM (Such as Linq to SQL)... in addition to SQL server so you can take full advantage of the "M" model part of MVC...